# React Redux extraReducers action payload unknown type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to make an axios get request and push the response.data in state with extraReducers, action.payload is of type unknown and therefore i can't set the campaignList state (same happens for the error)

```
export type initialStateType = {
    campaignStatus: string;
    campaignList: CampaignChart[];
    responseError: string | null;
}


const initialState: initialStateType = {
    campaignStatus: 'idle',
    campaignList: [],
    responseError: null,
    
}
export const fetchCampaigns = createAsyncThunk('campaigns/fetchCampaigns', async (_, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get<CampaignChart[]>(BASE_URL + '/campaigns');
        return response.data
    } catch(error){
        return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue({ error: error.message})
    }
})

export const campaignSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'campaign',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
    },
    extraReducers(builder) {
        builder
            .addCase(fetchCampaigns.pending, (state, action) => {
                state.campaignStatus = 'loading'
            })
            .addCase(fetchCampaigns.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                state.campaignStatus = 'succeeded'
                state.campaignList = state.campaignList.concat(action.payload)
            })
            .addCase(fetchCampaigns.rejected, (state, action) => {
                state.campaignStatus = 'failed'
                state.responseError = action.error.message
            })
    }
});
```

Also, could anyone help me mock this fetch call so i can unit test it with react-testing-library?

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: It was something telling me that action.payload is of type unknown and can't be added to campaignList which is of type <CampaignChart []>.


The solution was to add <CampaignChart[]> between createAsyncThunk and the parameters.

`
export const fetchCampaigns = createAsyncThunk <CampaignChart[]>('campaigns/fetchCampaigns', 
`

Something like this.

Answer (score 4):

The solution was to add `<CampaignChart[]>` between `createAsyncThunk` and the parameters.

```
export const fetchCampaigns = createAsyncThunk <CampaignChart[]>('campaigns/fetchCampaigns',
```